# Auto press a button to load data

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I currently have TamperMonkey installed and I am trying to make a script that auto clicks a button after the page has loaded so I can get the data I need.

There is a bug with one of our tools at work which they have not fixed and they never will. Basically, I need to access tasks from a SR, which load in separate window for each task. In the webpage for the task, I can see all the work that was done for that task. It usually auto populated itself with all the available data, and if there was something new submitted while you were on it, you would press refresh.

Now, we manually have to press refresh on each and every task to make it populate with data in the 1st place.
The refresh button is not loaded immediately, it takes about 3 seconds.

The button id on "inspect element" is:

id="refreshRecord_label"

I tried

```
function formSubmit(){
          document.getElementById("refreshRecord_label").submit();
    }

    window.onload=function(){
          window.setTimeout(formSubmit, 4000);
    };
```

But that doesn't work.

Could you please help? I am a complete noob at programming.

Comment: If your button is not inside a form, maybe change submit to click. Also, I don't see the need for "window.setTimeout", I would just use "setTimeout"

Comment: But javascript also has a built in reload if you only want to reload the page: location.reload();

Comment: Tried that. Does not do anything.

Comment: Please check the comments at the answer below for more info on the issue

Answer (score 0):

This will check every second if your button is loaded. When it's ready, the interval will be destroyed, so no further checks will be done and the button will be clicked automatically.

```
var interval;

window.onload = function(){
    interval = window.setInterval(submitWhenReady, 1000);
};


function submitWhenReady(){
    var button = document.getElementById("refreshRecord_label");
    if(button){
        window.clearInterval(interval);
        button.click();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does not work :( A bit of context.The initial issue with the whole thing was that we had an access in our system(didnt do anything special for what we know). That expired and when we tried to renew it, the IT or whoever guys that approve the requests told us that it does not do anything, that it is legacy obsolete. We tried to explain that they are wrong, because we got an e-mail when it expired and from then on, everytime we open a task we get around 4-5 pop-ups with the following message:An error occurred while fetching the FS type LOV: TypeError: x.setTitle is not a function

Comment: So, after we click that pop-up for about 5 times, we get to the task window but there is no auto refresh of the data like before. When we click the refresh button I get FSTask query failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'setValue' of undefined          But it does load the data and after I dismiss the pop-up everything works fine. But I have to do this for every task, and we have hundreds. The 1st thing I did is to use a block javascript alerts script to ignore the pop-ups which I will put in another comment, cause no more characters left.

Comment: addJS_Node (null, null, overrideSelectNativeJS_Functions);

function overrideSelectNativeJS_Functions () {
    window.alert = function alert (message) {
        console.log (message);
    };
}

function addJS_Node (text, s_URL, funcToRun) {
    var D                                   = document;
    var scriptNode                          = D.createElement ('script');
    scriptNode.type                         = "text/javascript";

Comment: if (text)       scriptNode.textContent  = text;
    if (s_URL)      scriptNode.src          = s_URL;
    if (funcToRun)  scriptNode.textContent  = '(' + funcToRun.toString() + ')()';

    var targ = D.getElementsByTagName ('head')[0] || D.body || D.documentElement;
    targ.appendChild (scriptNode);

Comment: Had to use 2 comments because of limit to the amount of characters I can use... So that script blocked the whole pop-up thing so I don't waste 10 seconds for each task. So the page loads fine and now I press refresh and it loads normally, with no annoying pop-ups. Now I am trying to get this button to auto click. Maybe the errors that I get above are interfering with the script?

Comment: 1 - Add that information to your question. Analizing code in comments is though.
2 - From your description, your problem has nothing to do with the code you've posted! If you can, please post the code associated with the errors you're getting ("TypeError: x.setTitle ")